# Questions about invertible matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have two $n \times n$ matrices $M,N$ that have an inverse, how do I show that:

1. ${M^T}$ has an inverse, with $(M^T)^{-1} = (M^{-1})^T$ ?
2. If $M$ and $N$ are orthogonal, then $MN$ is also orthogonal?

*Note: An invertible matrix $A$ is called **orthogonal** if $A^{-1} = A^T$*.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: For $(2) (MN)^{-1}=N^{-1}M^{-1}=N^TM^T=(MN)^T$

Comment: Wow, I had no idea it was that simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We have that: $I=I^T=(M^{-1}M)^T=M^T(M^{-1})^T$
   Multiplying both sides on the left by $(M^T)^{-1}$, we get:
   $(M^T)^{-1}=(M^{-1})^T$.
2. $(MN)^{-1}=N^{-1}M^{-1}=N^TM^T=(MN)^T$

Comment: What is being multiplied by ${({A^t})^{ - 1}}$? I don't understand.